# How to use one drive file picker in browser?

Tags: onedrive

I need to integrate One Driver file picker in my website. I am using this js lib to do the task.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//js.live.net/v5.0/wl.js"></script>
```

The code I wrote is

```
WL.init({ client_id: "000000004C1xxxxx", redirect_uri: 'https://xxx.net/' });
WL.login({
        scope: "wl.skydrive wl.signin"
    }).then(
        function(response) {
            WL.fileDialog({
                mode: "open",
                select: "multi"
            }).then(
                function (response) {
                },
                function (responseFailed) {
                }
            );
        },

        function(response) {
            log("Failed to authenticate.");
        }
    );
```

It showed the popup window, and went through the authentication process. However once I've logged in within the popup window. It just redirected to the redirect URL I provided, the file picker never showed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue by including the js script in my callback page, wl sdk will automatically handle the oauth process for you.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//js.live.net/v5.0/wl.js"></script>
```

It's weird as I could not find any documents related to how you should do with your callback page on MS developer website.

Answer (score 0):

Can you get the "Using the open from OneDrive picker" sample working on http://isdk.dev.live.com?

Comment: Yes, I can, I was using the same code from this page. However after I view the source of the callback page of that sample, I found the solution. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use the function below in your js file  and don't forget to include :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.live.net/v7.0/OneDrive.js"></script>




 function launchOneDrivePicker() {
        var odOptions = {
            clientId: "*******************************",
            action: "download",
            multiSelect: true,
            openInNewWindow: true,
            advanced: {
                queryParameters: "select=id,name,size,file,folder,photo",

                redirectUri: (Eneter your default url e.g :)"http://localhost:60666/WebForm1.aspx"
            },
            success: function (response) { /* success handler */      },
            cancel: function () { /* cancel handler */ },
            error: function (e) { /* error handler */ },
        };
        OneDrive.open(odOptions);
    }
```

I hope it works for everyone thanks.