# How to use OneDrive File Picker On Browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onedrive

I have same problem in this topic with AngularJS: [How to use one drive file picker in browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25357750/4246507)

I have add `<script type="text/javascript" src="//js.live.net/v5.0/wl.js"></script>`into my index.html page. But it can't work? Any idea?

**Update 1:** My Source Code like this:

```
WL.init({ client_id: clientId, redirect_uri: redirectUri });

WL.login({ "scope": "wl.skydrive wl.signin" }).then(
    function(response) {
        openFromSkyDrive();
    },
    function(response) {
        log("Failed to authenticate.");
    }
);

function openFromSkyDrive() {
    WL.fileDialog({
        mode: 'open',
        select: 'single'
    }).then(
        function(response) {
            log("The following file is being downloaded:");
            log("");

            var files = response.data.files;
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                var file = files[i];
                log(file.name);
                WL.download({ "path": file.id + "/content" });
            }
        },
        function(errorResponse) {
            log("WL.fileDialog errorResponse = " + JSON.stringify(errorResponse));
        }
    );
}

function log(message) {
    var child = document.createTextNode(message);
    var parent = document.getElementById('JsOutputDiv') || document.body;
    parent.appendChild(child);
    parent.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
}
```

And i click on the button, it show me a popup to login Onedrive. I fill username and password, then popup still show in redirectURI. The file picker not show.
Sorry about my first question.

Comment: ah come on, a script tag and a statement that it doesn't work is all the information you can provide? How do you expect anyone to help with just that?

Answer (score 0):

What do you see in the popup window after you try to sign in?   Can you confirm that your redirect URI defined when registering your application is the same as the index.html page hosting the picker?

Comment: I'm working on locahost. I upload my source code on my hosting then change RedirectURI. It work and show Onedrive file picker. But on locahost, i just redirect popup to my RedirectURI (http://www.example.com). So, i want it can work on locahost.

Comment: Since it works on your hosting provider but doesn't on your local machine, I would recommend creating an entry in your host file that maps your redirect URI to your localhost.   There are more details at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659751.aspx under "Testing web apps locally".   Hope this helps!